# How to open facebook app from my app

Tags: android, facebook

I want to open/launch  facebook or facebook-chat app from my app. I used the below code:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("facebook:/chat")));
```

Comment: Nothing specific to call facebook native app, you can use Intent.ACTION_SEND or start a webview with facebook.com url..

Answer (score 1):

Actually it looks like this. These URIs only work with the most recent version of the Facebook app. That's why we try catch:

```
public static Intent getOpenFacebookIntent(Context context) {

try {
    context.getPackageManager()
            .getPackageInfo("com.facebook.katana", 0); //Checks if FB is even installed.
    return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("fb://profile/254175194653125")); //Trys to make intent with FB's URI
} catch (Exception e) {
    return new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com/sentiapps")); //catches and opens a url to the desired page
}
```

}

In your Activity, to open it, call it like so:

```
Intent facebookIntent = getOpenFacebookIntent(this);
startActivity(facebookIntent);
```

Comment: com.facebook.katana refers your package which is used to check if you have facebook app